# Using DYRateView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

me again. I was hoping to use DYRateView (found here: https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView) to add a star rating to my TableViewCells. I'm currently using this code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
DYRateView *rateView = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78, 49, 100, 14)];
    rateView.rate = 4;
    rateView.alignment = RateViewAlignmentRight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rateView];
```

Now I've done all the basic checks like imported the header file and added the star images to the library, but it just refuses to work! If you could offer any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having trawled the internet more and more, I have discovered that there is a particular glitch with this API when used with the Storyboard. For anyone else having a similar issue, the problem comes from the `RateViewAlignmentRight;` code. It seems to bug out in UITableViewCells on Storyboard. Try setting it to `RateViewAlignmentLeft;`. Apologies to anyone who began to attempt a fix, sorry for wasting your time.

Hope this helps,
Regards,
Mike